# how to dynamically add conditions to the query based on what inputs you get from the client/form?

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, axios

i have input data for example :   sex = male,
i can query it like this:

```
$sex = $data['sex'];
            $query = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_information WHERE sex = $sex");
            echo json_encode($query);
```

but if i input sex = male and civil_status = single
this query works:

```
 $sex = $data['sex'];
            $civil_status = $data['civil_status'];
            $query = $this->db->rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_information WHERE sex = $sex AND
            civil_status = $civil_status");
            echo json_encode($query);
            return;
```

this is the problem: how can i dynamically change the condition based on the inputby user

Comment: _"i can query it like this"_ - Actually, that query would throw a syntax error since you're missing the quotes around the value. However, you should _really_ use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) with placeholders instead of injecting variables directly into the queries like that.

Comment: it won't throw an error because the value of male = 1 and female = 0, same with the civil status their value change when storing to database to int.

Comment: Fair enough, but you should probably edit the question though since it now says: `sex = male`, which confuses things.

Comment: is it possible to solve this problem bro? please help:)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. What do you mean by "merge this into one query"? The only difference is that the second query has a couple of more conditions and a limit. Not sure what to "merge" here? Or are you asking how to dynamically add conditions to the query based on what inputs you get from the client/form? Please edit your question and explain in more detail what you want.

Comment: I think you got the right question.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate a query based on conditions that recieved from client. something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_information";

$civil_status = $data['civil_status'];

if ($civil_status){
     $query .= " WHERE civil_status = '$civil_status'";
}
```

You can use query builders like [laravel Eloquent](https://github.com/illuminate/database) for simplicity

Comment: **Note:** Just want to again point out that you should _never_ put user data (or any unknown data) directly into your queries like that. It will make you open for SQL injection attacks. Always use prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: Ok thanks bro. Give me some example code @M.Eriksson

Comment: @MichaelAngeloCorral - [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you, Farid Saravi and @M.Eriksson